# Trying to iterate over a nested object from an API and return the data into my react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a nested object which is a little complicated since it has numeric value as ID of each entry.

```
"coins":
0:{...}29 items
1:{...}29 items
2:{...}29 items
3:{...}29 items
4:{...}29 items
```

This is my code, this is not working for me. Console log is returning data but the UI component is not being rendered

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./Homepage.css";
import CryptoCard from "../Card/Card";
import axios from "axios";

const Homepage = () => {
  const [coinData, setCoinData] = useState([], () => {
    const localData = localStorage.getItem("coinData");
    return localData ? JSON.parse(localData) : [];
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com/coins",
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "API_KEY",
      },
    };

    axios
      .request(options)
      .then((response) => {
        setCoinData(response.data.data.coins);
        // persist in localStorage
        localStorage.setItem(
          "coinData",
          JSON.stringify(response.data.data.coins)
        );
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);

  console.log("Coins names");
  coinData.forEach(function (coin) {
    console.log(coin.name);
  });

  const i = 0;
  return (
    <div className="homepage">
      <div className="heading">
        <h1>Discover</h1>
        <hr className="line" />
      </div>
      <div className="cards-container">
        {coinData?.forEach(function (coin) {
          <CryptoCard
            name={coin.name}
            coinUrl={coin.websiteUrl}
            duration="4 minutes ago"
            symbol={coin.symbol}
            rank={coin.rank}
            exchanges={coin.numberOfExchanges}
            price={coin.price}
          />;
        })}
        {/* <CryptoCard
          name={coinData[0]?.name}
          coinUrl={coinData[0]?.websiteUrl}
          duration="4 minutes ago"
          symbol={coinData[0]?.symbol}
          rank={coinData[0]?.rank}
          exchanges={coinData[0]?.numberOfExchanges}
          price={coinData[0]?.price}
        /> */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Homepage;
```

I need to iterate over this and return the data from each entry into my React component and I can not figure out how to iterate over them without a loop. Using loop does not work either for me.

Comment: You can use object.values() and then loop it through using .map function

Comment: I made the edit, please take a look at the question again. Thank you :)

Comment: You may find [`useLocalStorage`](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/) useful.

Comment: Can you console.log coinData and tell the format of your api response? Also What is the output of following code?

Comment: Yes, the console.log gives me the expected output. I get the names of all the coins. But when I am using for each to pass the strings to my cyptocard component, it is not rendering any cards on my homepage

Comment: The response from API in the console.log(coinData.names) is names in string format. The object is the same as the one I mentioned in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react you don't have to use forEach. Instead you have to use `.map` which is easy, declarative and do not mutate the original Array. With `forEach` if you alter some member of the coin value inside the loop, or even in the `CryptoCard` component, you are mutating the original array, which means mutate the react state, that's not allowed. But for this to work, please make sure to console log the `coinData` variable and check if it contains the value you expect.

```
        {coinData?.forEach(function (coin) {
          <CryptoCard
            name={coin.name}
            coinUrl={coin.websiteUrl}
            duration="4 minutes ago"
            symbol={coin.symbol}
            rank={coin.rank}
            exchanges={coin.numberOfExchanges}
            price={coin.price}
          />;
        })}
```

should be

```
        {(coinData|| []).map(coin => (
          <CryptoCard
            name={coin.name}
            coinUrl={coin.websiteUrl}
            duration="4 minutes ago"
            symbol={coin.symbol}
            rank={coin.rank}
            exchanges={coin.numberOfExchanges}
            price={coin.price}
          />;
        ))}
```

Comment: Thanks man! That worked! I was trying .map but could not figure out how to iterate so tried forEach. But .map works better! Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows:

```
{coinData?.map((coin) =>
    <CryptoCard
      name={coin.name}
      coinUrl={coin.websiteUrl}
      duration="4 minutes ago"
      symbol={coin.symbol}
      rank={coin.rank}
      exchanges={coin.numberOfExchanges}
      price={coin.price}
    />;
)}
```

`.map` will then return a list of your `CryptoCard` component.

Answer (score 0):

If the `console.log` statements are printing the intended values properly and the following snippet is not working,

```html
<div className="cards-container">
  {coinData?.forEach(function (coin) {
    <CryptoCard
      name={coin.name}
      coinUrl={coin.websiteUrl}
      duration="4 minutes ago"
      symbol={coin.symbol}
      rank={coin.rank}
      exchanges={coin.numberOfExchanges}
      price={coin.price}
    />;
 })}
</div>
```

It might be because you are not returning anything from inside the function inside the `forEach` loop. Try adding `return` before the component inside the function, like so

```
{coinData?.forEach(function (coin) {
  return (
    <CryptoCard
      name={coin.name}
      coinUrl={coin.websiteUrl}
      duration="4 minutes ago"
      symbol={coin.symbol}
      rank={coin.rank}
      exchanges={coin.numberOfExchanges}
      price={coin.price}
    />;
  )
})}
```

Comment: Added the return, still nothing.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help but .map() worked. Take a look at the other answers. Help is appreciated!